# React pass "this" to context provider value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I was playing around with useContext in a class component.
I've created a simple react (nextjs) application with one button that call a function in the context that update the state and therefore re-render the home component.

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../provider/TestProvider";

export default function Home() {
    let [contex] = useContext(UserContext);
    // Without the destructuring assignment
    // let contex = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => contex.addOne()}>Add 1</button>
            {contex.state.count.map((e) => (
                <div key={Math.random()}> {e} </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

```js
import { createContext, Component } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export default class TestProvider extends Component {
    state = {count: []};

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
    }

    addOne() {
        let oldState = [...this.state.count];
        oldState.push("test");
        this.setState({ count: oldState });
    }

    render() {
        return ( // Changing value to value={this}
            <UserContext.Provider value={[this]}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Note: The provider it's wrapped to the entire application, inside
`_app.js`

this is working fine, however I was wondering why I'm forced to pass
`this` inside an array?

```
value={[this]}
```

When I tried to pass only this (`value={this}`) and modify the context

```
let contex = useContext(UserContext)
```

the Home function doesn't react anymore on the change of the state, and therefore no rerender.

From my knowledge of programming both options should behave exactly the same.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are only "forced" to pass the context value as `value={[this]}` because that is how you are accessing it in the consumer.

```
let [contex] = useContext(UserContext);
```

Here you are using array ***destructuring assignment*** to get the context value ***out of*** the array and accessible.

```
contex.state.count
```

In other words, `this.state.count` and `contex.state.count` are the same thing.

It rather more that you are forced to consume it from an array because that is how it was provided: `value={[this]}`.

## Solution

Instead of passing the *entire* `this` object of the root parent class component it would be better to pass ***only*** what you need to, like ***only*** the `count` state and the `addOne` callback function.

Example:

```
export const UserContext = createContext({
  addOne: () => {},
  count: [],
});

export default class TestProvider extends Component {
  state = { count: [] };

  addOne = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: [...prevState.count, "test"],
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{ addOne: this.addOne, count }} // provided as object
      >
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../provider/TestProvider";

export default function Home() {
  const { addOne, count } = useContext(UserContext); // object destructuring assignment

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addOne}>Add 1</button>
      {count.map((e) => (
        <div key={e}>{e}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-pass-this-to-context-provider-value]

The main takeaway here though should be that however you are ***consuming*** the context value should match how you are ***providing*** it.

Comment: Thanks for the time! Passing `this` to che provider shuld be avoided or there are no problem? I'm working on an application that has a big context with a lot of functions, and passing then one by one can become messy. And than this doesn't really responde to the question: if I pass `this` and modify the consumer the component doesn't update anymore

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear what is the problem

Comment: @Sau1707 Yes, I'd say passing the `this` of the class component instance should be avoided. You should be explicit in what is being provided on the context. Sorry, my code had a couple issues. I've fixed them and added a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pass-this-to-context-provider-value-b7h3nm?file=/src/App.js) demo that updates and rerenders as one would expect it to.

Comment: I'll mark it solved since I'm gonna use your method, however I still wonder why the other one is not working. I've created a fork of your [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-pass-this-to-context-provider-value-forked-d3d3ii?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).  The `console.log` in  `addOne` get called but the home component don't re-render. 
In any case thanks  a lot, super well written and clear to anyone who need in the future

Comment: @Sau1707 I'll take a look at your sandbox.

Comment: @Sau1707 Oh, I see what is going on here. The `this` of the class component is a stable reference, which makes sense. If you instead did `value={{ ...this }}` then you will see the components rerender and update. So *technically* speaking, the context value itself isn't updating which seems to be why consumers are not rerendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248161/discussion-between-sau1707-and-drew-reese).